# Import sql database, denies me access to mine?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to import an sql dump into wamp->mysql. It imports fine but when I try to see the tables it shows an empty set. Upon doing this I lose access to mysql and cannot login. It is strange because I am able to import another database of the exact same model from a different server fine. I check the mysql log and I get this:

```
110616 14:27:24 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110616 14:27:24  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 3049592450
110616 14:27:25 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.db is wrong. Expected 22, found 20. The   table is probably corrupted
110616 14:27:25 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 29
110616 14:27:25 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
```

If anyone can give me details on what is happening and a way to restore my access without having to reinstall wamp that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am truly an idiot. The other database "root" has a password and it overwrites mine. All I needed to do was create a general admin user with all rights access. It also creates a new database with a new name where it inputs all the data instead of using the one I had chosen for it.